# Stopping setInterval in coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, clearinterval

How can I stop the setInterval in my script ? Alert working, `clearInterval` not, and there isn't any error in console.

```
order =  
  start_poll: ->
    interval = setInterval(@request, 60000)
  stop_polling: ->
    clearInterval order.start_poll()
    alert ('expired')
  request: ->
    id = $('#status_id').attr('data-id')
    $.get "/orders/#{id}", (data) ->
      console.log("#{data.status}")
      if data.status is 'expired'
        order.stop_polling()


$ ->
  order.start_poll()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) returns a new timer ID every time you call it and you pass that ID [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) to stop that specific timer. So when you do this:

```
clearInterval order.start_poll()
```

you're just starting a new timer and immediately stopping it, this won't have any affect whatsoever on other timers.

You need to store the ID so that you can cancel it later:

```
order =  
  start_poll: ->
    @interval = setInterval(@request, 60000)
  stop_polling: ->
    clearInterval(@interval) if(@interval)
    alert('expired')
  #...
```

You might want to add a `@stop_polling()` call to the top of `start_poll` too. This isn't necessary but it can't hurt and it will help prevent future bugs if you decide to change how you interact with the polling.