# About nesting setInterval

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I m actually trying to nest some setInterval call.

Actually, I have one that executes a job each 5 minutes, and inside of, I have one that executes a job each minutes.

The two are linked and it's important.

Heres the code :

```
  loadBuilds: ->
    @sendRequest()
    # First set interval
    setInterval =>
      @sendRequest()
    , 1000 * 60 * 5

  sendRequest:->
    request @jconf.url,(error,response,body)=>
      if !error && response.statusCode == 200
        @element.innerHTML = ''
        title = document.createElement 'h4'
        title.textContent = 'Super item'
        subTitle = document.createElement 'p'


        # Second set interval
        date = new Date();
        subTitle.textContent = 'Last check : ' + moment(date).fromNow()
        setInterval ->
          moment(date).fromNow()
          subTitle.textContent = 'Last check : ' + moment(date).fromNow()
        ,1000*60

        @element.appendChild title
        @element.appendChild subTitle
        @parseContent body
```

I was wondering in that case if :

When the **second tick of the first set interval** is called, does **the second set Interval of the first setInterval** is cleared, I mean there frees its memory or should I make it manually ?

I mean there, should I have a heap memory issue if I let the two setInterval works together, getting more and more memory without cleaning the previous setInterval ?

Comment: I don't know coffeescript that well, but as there is NO clearInterval I imagine a new "inner" interval is created every 5 minutes and the old one keeps going too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code, taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872015/stopping-setinterval-in-coffeescript) , is used to stop a `setInterval` after storing its ID:

```
order =  
start_poll: ->
   @interval = setInterval(@request, 60000)
stop_polling: ->
   clearInterval(@interval) if(@interval)
   alert ('expired')
#...
```